# Python - Replace string with a twist

Tags: python, text, replace

Hi Stackoverflow users,

I have a problem which I would like to solve which involves converting 'key words' to a 'generic words' bucket.

I have a table which I loop through to replace certain words e.g.

```
**genericword**          **keyword**

slowness               slow speed

slowness               internet slow
```

A dataset called **test_data** contains a text column called **feedback_text** which contains a sentence.  What I would like to do is replace any text which is within the **keyword** group with **genericword**.

e.g. where **feedback_text** = 'the internet has slow speeds' should be replaced by 'the internet is slowness'

however this is coming up with 'the internet is slownesss' with an extra 's', when using the below code,

test_data['feedback_text'].str.replace(row['keyword'],row['genericword'])

How do I work around this?

Thanks

Comment: Specify some input output

Comment: You could state that if your text is not enclosed by spaces (or another delimiter), that you just remove the text until the delimiter and then replace with the alternative. That way the extra s would disappear

Comment: Should *"slow speeds"* be replaced? Why isn't it a keyword?

Answer (score 0):

Replace instances of "keyword" concatenated with the character "s" then replace all instances of keyword in the next line. This gets rid of the s if that's the only thing bothering you.

`test_data['feedback_text'].str.replace(row['keyword'] + 's',row['genericword']);
test_data['feedback_text'].str.replace(row['keyword'],row['genericword']);`

Comment: Replace instances of "keyword" concatenated with the character "s" then replace all instances of keyword in the next line. This gets rid of the s if that's the only thing bothering you.

Comment: Thanks. Did it, sorry, new here.